# How to create a submit button template in Oracle APEX?

Tags: templates, button, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a template for a button in Oracle APEX but I don't seem to have access to the appropriate substitution strings to make it work.  For non-templated buttons APEX seems to insert a handler for the onclick event that calls `doSubmit('buttonName')`  Unfortunately, when I go to create a template the only substitution strings I seem to get access to are #LINK#, #LABEL#, #BUTTON_ATTRIBUTES#, and #BUTTON_ID#.  How do I get to the button name in order to make the `doSubmit` work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **href="#LINK#"**.  At runtime, Apex replaces this with **href="javascript:doSubmit('XXX')"** where 'XXX' is the Button Request Value associated with the button.

Comment: Works great!  Need to use the onClick attribute instead of the href attribute in my case though.  Thanks!